# What pattern is this that uses an arrow function in React?

Tags: reactjs

I’m reading [this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-recommended-reactjs-tips-and-best-practices-6064d4b8e26f) and am seeing an arrow function used inside a component like so:

```
<Hoverable>
 {hovered => <div>{hovered ? "I’m hovered!" : "I’m not hovered"}</div>}
</Hoverable>
```

What exactly is this pattern, and when is it useful?

Comment: Anything can be passed as `children` in React, providing that the component it's passed to knows how to handle it.

Comment: [function as children](https://medium.com/merrickchristensen/function-as-child-components-5f3920a9ace9)

Comment: This is called render props, or props as a child, whenever you need to access a dynamic value you can pass a function as a child to a react component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a function `children` prop. It's a way to pass arguments/properties to a child components that don't necessarily need to receive the value as a prop themselves but could alter something like the layout of a container component.

If you have a parent component:

```js
const Parent = props => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false)
    return (
        <div>
            {props.children(visible)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then you can utilize that `visible` state value in your child component like so...

```js
const Container = () => (
    <Parent>
        {visible => (
            <span style={visible ? undefined : { display: 'none' }}>
                My possibly visible text
            </span>
        )}
    </Parent>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it right after I posted. It’s a [function as a child](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/6/Using-Functions-as-Children-and-Render-Props-in-React-Components).